# How to fix Content Security Policy error? (Chrome Extension)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

I was building a chrome extension and used some icons from font awesome. However, those icons aren't loading because of the following error-

[image]

For reference, here is the manifest.json file-

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Safe and Secure",
    "description": "Every security tool at one place.",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "icons": {"128": "logo_128.png"},
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "images/logo.png",
        "default_popup": "index.html"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Chrome Extensions by default have a `Content Security Policy` of only files located within the extensions directory as specified [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_security_policy). The reason is so your extension's users are not vulnerable to malicous  code that could be brought in from a website.

If you want to use the font-awesome script for icons, you must specify so in your manifest.json.

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Safe and Secure",
    "description": "Every security tool at one place.",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "icons": {"128": "logo_128.png"},
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "images/logo.png",
        "default_popup": "index.html"
    }
    // add this line
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://example.com; object-src 'self'",
}
```

The above is just an example of how you would bring it in. I would check the website linked above in order to find an example that matches your use-case.

Comment: I added this to manifest.json- `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'self"` and now I am getting two errors- `'content_security_policy': Ignored insecure CSP value "'unsafe-inline'" in directive 'script-src'.` and `'content_security_policy': Ignored insecure CSP value "'self" in directive 'object-src'.`

Comment: In your case, instead of adding ‘unsafe-eval’ you should be adding the websites domain https://kit.fontawesome.com (include the https:// part). Remember that you are bringing in a remote script so you need to specify from which website you are bringing in the script.

Comment: Again, its just ignoring the value that i give :(